# Hiding div after a few seconds ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, hide, transition

I'm trying to hide a div after a few seconds on ReactJS. Here is my code so far:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#submitmsg').fadeOut('fast');
}, 3000);

<div id="submitmsg">
    {message && <span> Messaged received. I'll respond to your query ASAP!  </span> }
 </div>
```

I'm getting an error, saying that the "$" is undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$` is a sign for jquery
in react we would say

```
  document.getElementById('#submitmsg').fadeOut('fast');
```

also i would use a easier way by declaring a boolean is usestate

```
const Component = () =>{
  const [showElement,setShowElement] = React.useState(true)
  useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(function() {
      setShowElement(false)
         }, 3000);
       },
   [])
      
  return(
    <div>
       {showElement?<div>I'm here and i will be gone</div>:<></>} 
    </div>
  )
}
```

## Update:

here i created a codesandbox example

and here is the whole code it is working fine when i try it as you can see in codesandbox above

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [showElement, setShowElement] = React.useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      setShowElement(false);
    }, 10000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {showElement ? (
          <div
            style={{
              height: "100vh",
              background: "black",
              color: "white",
              fontSize: "30px",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              fontFamily: "roboto",
              opacity: showElement ? 1 : 0
            }}
          >
            I'm here and i will be gone
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}{" "}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default MyComponent;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-rosalind-o9pds?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hmm, I tried both and it still doesnt seem to work.
1) For the first answer, it says document.getElementById(...) is null and fadeOut isnt a function 
2) For the second one, it says there isnt anything return

Comment: I updated the answer, check out the end of answer.

Comment: Is there another way? I've been trying to implement it on my app and i've been facing quite a few errors

Comment: The code as you see is running in the mentioned link for codesandbox and it is working when i implement it myself, i will also paste the code in here, you can copy it and paste it in your app, but more importantly try to understand it.

Comment: Here's a link to my codebox, I've added a snippet of my code : https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-dew-ugfp9?file=/src/App.js

Yeah, the thing is I don't really get your solution at the return portion

Comment: You can solve the problem by wrapping the return elements with new div or in another word, put the logic as a child of new div like i did in the code, you only added the logic which it will not work since render function should always return a DOM element or a fragment.

Comment: I also edited the sandbox you've made https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-engelbart-lnjlz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Haha I really don't know whats wrong man, it works in the sandbox but when I paste my code over, there isn't any error. but the text doesnt show. Heres a link to what im actually trying to do : https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-bartik-mtfj0

I wanted the text to appear and disappear after I click the send button..

Comment: I got it, i made another sandbox which does what you said. I hope it helps you. https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-currying-rsw67?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I want to like the second example, though it doesn't actually fade. It just causes the component to re-render without the div. Any ideas for making the second example work with a fade?